# How to make isort always produce multi-line output when there are multiple imports on a line?

Tags: python, isort

I'm currently using  `isort --profile=black --line-length=79` as a linter in my project for python files.

This produces the Vertical Hanging Indent (mode 3 in [isort's documentation](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/multi_line_output_modes.html) kind of output:

```
from third_party import (
    lib1,
    lib2,
    lib3,
    lib4,
)
```

This multiline mode only applies if the line is longer than 79 characters, though. Is there a mode that cause a multiline output as soon as there are two or more imports on the same line, no matter how long the line is?

I tried hacking it with  `isort -m=3 --trailing-comma --line-length=1`, but shorter line length will cause multiline output even when there is a single import, which I don't want:

```
from third_party import (
    lib1,
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `--force-grid-wrap 2` flag in the CLI or set in the settings file like `pyproject.toml` option `force_grid_wrap = 2`. This would force isort to produce multiline output for 2 or more imports, regardless of line length. [More info about this option](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#force-grid-wrap)