# isort config to always have multiple imports in parenthesis

Tags: python, isort

I am looking for an isort config to have one line per import if it's a single import but as soon as you have multiple imports it switches to parenthesis, so it would look like the following

```
from something import one_thing
from another.thing import (
    uno,
    due,
    tres,
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same question: [How to make isort always produce multi-line output when there are multiple imports on a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69205085/how-to-make-isort-always-produce-multi-line-output-when-there-are-multiple-impor)

See the first comment.

Use `force_grid_wrap = X` where X is the threshold of imports before wrapping them. Note, you should still use the `multi_line_output` option to set how you want the wrapped imports to actually look like.

For example:

```
multi_line_output = 3
force_grid_wrap = 2
```

Turns this:

```
from connector import conn
from logger import log
from exceptions import EmptyFieldException, MissingBodyException
```

Into this:

```
from connector import conn
from logger import log
from exceptions import (
    EmptyFieldException,
    MissingBodyException
)
```